# NSWindowController displays nib before windowDidLoad finishes

Tags: xcode, macos

When I try launching my app through Spotlight without building it through XCode, the `NSWindowController` displays the unmodified nib (with the standard gray background color, etc) for a split second before `windowDidLoad` finishes. This looks awful, since views are in the wrong places and aren't colored correctly.

I tried removing everything from `windowDidLoad` to see if something in there was slowing it down, but that didn't improve things. I also tried moving the setting of the background color to `initWithWindowNibName`, but that didn't help either.

Is there a way to delay showing the window while it finishes loading?

Here's the code I'm using to initialize the `NSWindowController`:

```
self.windowController = [[WindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"WindowController"];
[self.windowController showWindow:self];
[[self.windowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable NSWindowController's "visible at launch" property in Interface Builder.

(Of course, I post the question then immediately figure out the answer.)